# jquery slider stops working when page is refreshed in FireFox only

Tags: jquery

I have a slider that I have been using for a long time without problems, however, I have now discovered that in FireFox from I think version 25 onwards sometimes the slider runs properly on page load and other times it doesn't, if it works and I refresh the page with the refresh icon it may or not work, if I go into the address bar and press return it works.

It works fine on IE, Chrome, Safari and Opera, I have uploaded it to the site below if anyone can help;

Thanks

Comment: yes, i can reproduce the error, and got this message NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE in console..., and it is related to this line of your jquery slideshow: context.drawImage(sour[0],newL,newT,newW,newH);  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847713/component-returned-failure-code-0x80040111-ns-error-not-available Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. For me, the problem was fixed by commenting out that line of jQuery:

```
context.drawImage(sour[0],newL,newT,newW,newH);
```

In other words, and I don't mean to patronize:

```
// context.drawImage(sour[0],newL,newT,newW,newH);
```

Your site could potentially need that line of code, but at least give it a try and hope everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up encapsulating the offending code in a dummy setTimeout function which seems to have worked

```
                        setTimeout(function () {
                        if (hasCanvas) {
                            context.drawImage(sour[0],newL,newT,newW,newH);
                            if (sourbw.length>0) {      
                                    contextbw.drawImage(sourbw[0],newL,newT,newW,newH);
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        sour.parent().find('.canvas-now-bw').cssAnimate({'opacity':'0.0'},{duration:newitem.data('colortransition')*1000,queue:false});
                                    },500);

                            }
                        } 
                        }, 0)
```