# How do I enable copy to clipboard in Firefox on Linux?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I released a new version of a [firefox webextension, Copy 
All Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-all-tabs/?src=api) last night. The code is [open source and available on github](https://github.com/charlesbrandt/copy_all_tabs).

The new version fixes many bugs and is overall more stable. It works as expected on Windows and Mac (Firefox 61).

However, when I was testing on Linux (both Firefox 60 and 61), the "Copy Tabs" function fails.

https://www.google.com/search?q=Component+returned+failure+code&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab

[Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847713/component-returned-failure-code-0x80040111-ns-error-not-available)

The function that fails on Linux is located in this file:
https://github.com/charlesbrandt/copy_all_tabs/blob/master/ff-web_extension/background.js

The major shift was moving the copy and paste functions from a content script that was injected into the active tab's page to the background.js file. The content script approach was failing for Firefox specific pages (e.g. about:debugging) for security reasons.

Given the discrepancy, I'm inclined to think it has something to do with Firefox, but if it's a problem in the webextension I'd be happy to fix it.

If this is a bug in firefox, what is the best way to report it?

Alternatively, does anyone have a suggestion for how modify the extension so that it works effectively on all platforms?

Update:
I followed @Dexter's advice and filed a bug in Bugzilla:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1473780

Since that time, the plugin eventually started working in newer versions of the browser.

Comment: One good way to report the problem would be to file a bug in [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=WebExtensions) or reach out to the devs in #developers on irc.mozilla.org

Answer (score 0):

I do NOT know if this might be your issue, but here goes.

Recently switched from Windows to Pop! OS (derived from Ubuntu/GNOME). Had problems with certain Firefox Browser Extensions, specifically those enabling the copying of links from webpages and subsequent pasting them into, say, GVim.

UNTIL I followed the instructions here:

How to Customize the GNOME Shell in Ubuntu Using Extensions
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/customize-gnome-shell-extensions/

WRT installing GNOME Tweak, GNOME Shell Extensions, and Shell Extensions for Firefox.

I would suggest you try this and see if it helps. I hope it does.